# Stopping text from being italic in shaded environment

Tags: environments, italic, shading

I'm having trouble making the text within my shaded environment appear normal without being italic. I've provided a MWE below.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\definecolor{shade}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
    \newmdtheoremenv [backgroundcolor=shade,
    innertopmargin =12pt, innerbottommargin =12pt,
    splittopskip = \topskip, skipbelow= 6pt, skipabove=6pt,
    topline=true,bottomline=false,leftline=false,rightline=false,]{shaded}{}
    \renewcommand\theshaded{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{shaded} text \end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to fix this!

Comment: Which theorem package do you use?

Comment: Ah, I apologise for not including that. `\usepackage{thmtools}` didn't paste over from my tex file.

Comment: theorem environments tend to be italic by default,  you could over-ride that, but do you actually want this to be a theorem environment (`\newmdtheoremenv `) or just a general shaded block?

Comment: I want it to be a theorem environment, @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: But it has no title and no number. What's the difference with a simple`mdframed` environment?

Comment: For the option to add a title in place of 'Theorem' or 'Proposition' etc. @Bernard. I like having the option for a title :-)

Comment: A numbered title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the package `ntheorem` you can declare it.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{letterpaper}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\definecolor{shade}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
      \newmdtheoremenv [backgroundcolor=shade,
      ntheorem,
      innertopmargin =12pt, innerbottommargin =12pt,
      splittopskip = \topskip, skipbelow= 6pt, skipabove=6pt,
      topline=true,bottomline=false,leftline=false,rightline=false,]{shaded}{}
      \renewcommand\theshaded{}

\begin{document}
      \begin{shaded} text \end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I'm guessing that the `\normalfont` can be adjusted to include different types of fonts?

Comment: Yes. For example `\theorembodyfont{\normalfont \sffamily}` or whatever font you have defined.

Comment: Wicked! That's solved my problem. Thanks for the info on the new package.

Comment: Well, actually it is quite an old package (started in 1997). :)

Answer (score 3):

A way to do it with `thmtools` and `amsthm`, although I don't see the difference with a plain `mdframed` environment with a user-defined style:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}%
\usepackage{mdframed, thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{shade}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\mdfdefinestyle{myshadestyle}{backgroundcolor=shade,
innertopmargin=12pt, innerbottommargin=12pt,
splittopskip=\topskip, skipbelow= 6pt, skipabove=6pt,
topline=true,bottomline=false,leftline=false,rightline=false,}
\mdfsetup{style=myshadestyle}   

   \makeatletter
   \def\thmt@headstyle@empty{%
   \relax}
    \makeatother 
    \declaretheoremstyle[
    headstyle=empty,
    notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
    headpunct={\leavevmode\hspace{-0.9\fontdimen2\font}},
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    ]{mystyle}

\declaretheorem[style=mystyle, mdframed]{shaded}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=myshadestyle] 
  \lipsum[11]
\end{mdframed}

\begin{shaded}%[style=myshadestyle]
  \lipsum[11]
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

[image]